# No response from the server when sending a POST request using fuel and Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, http-post

There was a problem. Using the fuel library, I create a post request to the server. A special features of the request is authorization via the bearer token and the json content type. Below is the code:

```
fun callApi(site:String, token: String):String {

  val(request, response, result) = Fuel.post(site)
    .authentication()
    .bearer(token)
    .jsonBody("{\"instrumentStatus\":\"INSTRUMENT_STATUS_UNSPECIFIED\"}")
    .responseString()

return response.toString()   }
```

As seen above, I have created a function that accepts a path and a pre-known bearer token.

In the main.kt I create two variables: site and token. Then I call the callApi function,  passing return data  to TextView:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val token = "t.GtiJaNIjpWy-Iw4sFSFvIEQHdCxxQS7Nz1HHTP4tM3pmfrXPyP3LbqJnbJln2Lpv85BiMK-ry3ynhzFFVgJM_A"
    val site = "https://invest-public-api.tinkoff.ru/rest/tinkoff.public.invest.api.contract.v1.InstrumentsService/Bonds"

    val textView: TextView = findViewById(R.id.textView)

     textView.text = callApi(site,token)
}
```

}

To check the server's workability, I used the Postman program. If I specify the same thing there, the answer comes in.

Please help me. What am I doing wrong? Why aren't the data coming in?

Comment: Did you add internet permissions in the manifest? checked to handle ssl?

Comment: Thank you for requst :)
Internet permission added. But, I do not know how to check to handle ssl...How can this affect the work?

@Fabio